# C++ Make asks for a file that doesn't exist

Tags: c++, makefile

When I try to build/compile my code, I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '../../Source/GardenCounter.cpp', needed by 'build/intermediate/Debug/GardenCounter_15332182.o'.  Stop.
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'make QUIET=0'" terminated with exit code: 2.
```

I don't have a file named `GardenCounter.cpp` anymore. I deleted it and yet it is still asking for it. I tried to delete the old .o and .d files and recompile everything from scratch but I'm still being asked for this.

Comment: Show us your makefile.

Comment: You need to remove the dependency on that file from your Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it would help to post your Makefile here. Without it, it's hard to know what the specific issue is. But here are some things to try off the top of my head:

-Look for the name of that source file in your Makefile. Did you remove it from all the build dependencies there?

-Is there a wildcard expression used somewhere in your Makefile that might be picking up that name from some other file? Possibly a header or an intermediate build file?